# Root Navlink always get active class React Router Dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using `react-router-dom: 4.2.2`. I can add `activeClassName` to the current URL. But surprisingly the class is always added to root URL.

While visiting a page, for example the error page like the screenshot below, the home navlink also getting the activeClass.

[image]

**Update:** In the above screenshot I have showed that I visited `http://localhost:3000/#/error`. So, the `active-link` should be added to the `Love Error?` NavLink only. But as you can see it is also added to `Home` NavLink too.

Here is my navbar code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

export const NavigationBar = () => (
  <ul className="horizontal-menu">
    <li> <NavLink to = '/' activeClassName="active-link">Home</NavLink> </li>
    <li> <NavLink to = '/about' activeClassName="active-link">About Us</NavLink> </li>
    <li> <NavLink to = '/error' activeClassName="active-link">Love Error?</NavLink> </li>
  </ul>
)
```

For routing I have used the following Switch:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path = '/' component = {Home} />
  <Route exact path = '/about' component = {AboutUs} />
  <Route exact path = '/error' component = {Error404} />
  <Route path = "/news/:id" component = {NewsDetail} />
  <Route path="*" component={Error404} />
</Switch>
```

How can I get the expected behavior?

Comment: post a sample url that is causing error

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier, updated my question. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: Tip: Sort by the latest answers, old answers might not work

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You have to use `isActive={}` to add additional verification to ensure whether the link is active.

[document](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md)

Working [jsFiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/tophergates/jb3jkxww/light/). (fiddle is not created by me)

Code you need to add is like below

Example in jsfiddle

```
<li><NavLink to="/" isActive={checkActive}>Home</NavLink></li>
```

Change in your code

```
<li> <NavLink to='/' activeClassName="active-link" isActive={checkActive}>Home</NavLink> </li>
```

check the isActive prop and "**checkActive**" is a function.

```
const checkActive = (match, location) => {
    //some additional logic to verify you are in the home URI
    if(!location) return false;
    const {pathname} = location;
    console.log(pathname);
    return pathname === "/";
}
```

Another config you can use is "**exact**" but It is not possible to demonstrate it in a jsFiddle. 
I think the code would be like

```
<li> <NavLink exact to='/' activeClassName="active-link">Home</NavLink> </li>
```

Hope this helps. And let me know if you need more info.

Comment: It works like a charm! But I wonder if there is no default method rather than this custom handwritten method. Thank you.

Comment: added another usable config hope that will help you

Comment: This answer does work but there is a simple, documented way built in already, [as answered by](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48393110/397122) @digitalh2o

Comment: Adding exact attribute on NavLink worked perfect for me. Thanks!

Comment: Adding exact worked for me. But as I am new to reactjs I did not realize I had to add / in front of each path. So just in case someone else has the same problem:
`
        <NavLink exact activeClassName="selected"  to="/choose"  >choose</NavLink>
         <NavLink exact activeClassName="selected"  to="/Plan"  plan</NavLink>`

Comment: `exact` Worked Like Charm :)

Answer (score 48):

I've found that adding `exact` before the first `activeClassName` works as well. So for example, your set up can be:

```
export const NavigationBar = () => (
  <ul className="horizontal-menu">
    <li><NavLink to='/' exact activeClassName="active-link">Home</NavLink> 
    </li>
    ....remaining NavLinks
  </ul>
)
```

Comment: Sometimes, if you have additional data in the URL for example some filters, then it won't really work. The best solution then is to have a function that will decide about that. That's why the answer above is selected.

Answer (score 18):

You can use `exact` keyword for active class such as

```
<NavLink exact to ='/'>Home</NavLink>
```

it will generate like that

```
<a href="/" class="active" aria-current="page">Home</a>
```

and if you will get another page then it will be like that

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. No extra functions needed.

Comment: I'm using the exact on all my links. However, the home page link is still active.

Comment: @Erik make sure you removed the static active class

Comment: aria-current="page" is not needed cause 'page' is the default value [=)](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink#:~:text=can%20be%20passed.-,aria%2Dcurrent%3A%20string,Defaults%20to%20%22page%22.,-Based%20on%20WAI)

Comment: 2022 Version 6+  you'll want to use the "end" attribute. That little tidbit is tucked away in the new docs.

Comment: @gumball so much frustration until I saw your comment about `end`, thank you.  Odd name for the variable too.

Answer (score 5):

The correct answer in 2022 is to use the `end` prop.

```
<NavLink end {...props} />
```

**As per the docs:**

*If the end prop is used, it will ensure this component isn't matched as "active" when its descendant paths are matched. For example, to render a link that is only active at the website root and not any other URLs, you can use*

```
<NavLink to="/" end>
  Home
</NavLink>
```

Reference: https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/api

Answer (score 3):

Working fine for me

```
<ul className="menu nav navbar-nav">
      <li><NavLink exact to="/" activeClassName="active-link active2">Home</NavLink></li>
      <li><NavLink to="/financial-summary" activeClassName="active-link active2">Financial Summary</NavLink></li>
      <li><NavLink to="/account-statement" activeClassName="active-link active2">Account Statement</NavLink></li>
      <li><NavLink to="/tools" activeClassName="active-link active2">Tools</NavLink></li>
      <li><NavLink to="/service-charges" activeClassName="active-link active2">Service Charges & Important Information</NavLink></li>
    </ul>
```

css

```
.active2, .active2 a:link, .active2 a:visited{
    background: #004B8D !important;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

I recently came across this issue and solved it by simply adding:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
```

and then wrapped the component with:

```
export default withRouter(Component);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change in your code

```
<li> <NavLink to='/' activeClassName="active-link" isActive={checkActive}>Home</NavLink> </li>
```

and then

```
const checkActive = (match, location) => {
  console.log(location);
  if (!location) return false;
  const { pathname } = location;
  const { url } = match;
  return pathname === url ? true : false;
};
```

- note *

> ```
> const { pathname } = location;
> const { url } = match;
> return pathname === url ? true : false;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I am learning React now and just came across the same problem. I tried the following and it worked for me.

So, I have 3 navigational links.

```
<li><NavLink to="/home">Home</NavLink></li>
<li><NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink></li>
<li><NavLink to="/contact">Contact</NavLink></li>
```

But I added 4 routes.

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Home}></Route>
<Route path="/home" component={Home}></Route>
<Route path="/about" component={About}></Route>
<Route path="/contact" component={Contact}></Route>
```

I added 2 routes (/ and /home) for the same component (Home). This way, the react-router-dom seems to add the class 'active' only to the link that you click.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use `<Navlink>` on single page website and anchor-links, make sure to replace `<BrowserRouter>` with `<HashRouter>`!

I had to remove the slash to reach my anchor text: `<HashRouter hashType='noslash'>`

With this setup,

```
<li><NavLink to="about">About</NavLink></li>
```

will render

```
<a href="#about" aria-current="page" class="active">About</a>
```

[Documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter)

Answer (score -1):

**I am using LinkContainer from react-router-bootstrap**, I was still having an issue like this. The home link was always active.

I have solved it by using an **exact keyword for the path of the link** like this. I hope if you will use this and have any issue regarding this, so it can help.
cheers.

Header.js component :

```
  <LinkContainer to="/" exact>
     <Nav.Link>
       <i className="fas fa-home mr-1"></i>Home
     </Nav.Link>
  </LinkContainer>
```

and App.js component :

```
 <Route path="/" component={HomeScreen} exact />
 <Route path="/about" component={AboutScreen} exact />
 <Route path="/blogs" component={BlogScreen} exact />
```

Comment: There is no Nav.Link in react router